# Group by query sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to count the number of alerts and the number of alerts processed by user and  type type = C and M
I started with this query it gives me the number of major and critical alerts right but I'm stuck for numbers of alerts processed

```
SELECT 
  TYPE,
  user_name,
  COUNT(type_alertes) AS nb, 
  id_user,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS critique,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS majeur 
FROM stat_alert  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf ON user_qdf.`id` = id_user 
WHERE 
  user_qdf.`id`=id_user 
  AND TYPE IN ('M', 'C')
GROUP BY id_user
```

who can help me

Comment: Add type, user_name in group by

Comment: why are you joining the same tables multiple times? And I have doubt on your joining. Where is the joining field between table user_qdf and id_user

Comment: @polin It will do full join instead of left outer in that situation. Is COUNT(type_alertes) AS nb equal of sum critique and majeur?

Comment: Can you please share sample of your data? and what end result you want?

Comment: You can remove your CASE statements and just do "TYPE = 'C'", since the '=' function returns a 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want number of all alerts and from that number of C and number of M then

```
SELECT 
  user_name,
  COUNT(type_alertes) AS nb, 
  id_user,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS critique,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS majeur 
FROM stat_alert  
 JOIN user_qdf ON user_qdf.`id` = id_user 
GROUP BY id_user, user_name
```

should do that.
I assume that user_name is from user_qdf table and other are from stat_alert and id_user is not null.

EDIT: For sum of alertes

```
SELECT 
  user_name,
  COUNT(type_alertes) AS nb, 
  id_user,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS critique,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS majeur 
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='M' OR TYPE = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS both_c_and_m
FROM stat_alert  
 JOIN user_qdf ON user_qdf.`id` = id_user 
GROUP BY id_user, user_name
```

EDIT2:

```
SELECT 
  user_name,
  COUNT(type_alertes) AS nb, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='C' THEN type_alertes ELSE 0 END) AS critique_alerts,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='M' THEN type_alertes ELSE 0 END) AS majeur_alertes
  id_user,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS critique,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS majeur 
FROM stat_alert  
 JOIN user_qdf ON user_qdf.`id` = id_user 
WHERE TYPE in ('C','M')
GROUP BY id_user, user_name
```

is that what you want?

Comment: I'm stuck for numbers of alerts processed (colmun type_alertes) if type=C and if type =M

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want. Do you want to count C and M for every type_alertes? TYPE is a user_qdf column and type_alertes is stat_alert column?

Comment: I would like to type-alert as I do for major critical and count the number of alerts drafts for type = C and the same for type = M

Comment: what are "alerts processed" or "alert drafts" ?

Comment: at the beginning column type_alertes is null then i have this query UPDATE stat_alert  SET stat_alert.`type_alertes` = 1 WHERE cmts IS NOT NULL AND id_user IS NOT NULL"; I want this column to count the numbers for type = c and the same for type =M